# How to know if Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load() succeeded?

Tags: magento-1.8, database, customer, model

I want to know what if a customer ID I was trying to load was invalid. When I do this:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(12345);
```

If this customer exists, I get the data.

The problem is, if the customer ID doesn't exist, I still get something:

```
array (size=2)
  'created_at' => string '2016-05-24T15:59:18+00:00' (length=25)
  'group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I needed a way where I can sort of say,

```
if(!$customer) {....
```

or

```
if(count($customer) < 1) { ....
```

But since there is always something in the returned array, **how can I really know if a customer exists in the database**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, the right test is to check whether the loaded object has an ID.

```
if ($customer->getId()) {
    // This is an existing customer
} else {
    // This is not an existing customer
}
```

Comment: depends on the case, it's sometimes better to check if $customer is set at all.  `if ($customer && $customer->getId())` If $customer is null you get an error, because `getId()` doesn't exists. To be 100% sure, use `try` / `catch`

Comment: @Pawel well in the case of the OP, he's using `load()` on `Mage::getModel('customer/customer')`. So he will always get a `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` object even if there's no customer with that id. That's how the load method works. Adding `if ($customer)` is useless as it'll always be true